# Menu options toggle?

Tags: jquery, menu

First post, first question.

I'm a jQuery beginner so bear with me.
I have a menu that has 3 options. I need the code to toggle them - when an option is active/activated the other are inactive/deactivated (when deactivated, run respective *_deactivate() function). In order to have a neat menu, I've create in/out animations.
I've checked some post but haven't been able to apply the solutions to my problem.

Menu's code:

```
// Menu button "A Empresa" mouse events ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤

  $('#aEmpresa').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150);
    $("#aEmpresa_underline").animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#aEmpresa').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
    $("#aEmpresa_underline").stop(true).animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'0px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#aEmpresa').on('click', function(){
    $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#000000'}, 150);
    $("#aEmpresa p").css({'font-weight':'bold'}, 150);
    $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-22px'}, 150);
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
  });

  function aEmpresa_deactivate(){
    $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
    $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150,
      function(){
        $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-22px'}, 150);
        $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
        $("#aEmpresa p").css({'font-weight':'normal'}, 150,
          function(){
            $('#aEmpresa').on();
            $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

// Menu button "A Nossa Arte" mouse events ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤

  $('#aNossaArte').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    $("#aNossaArte p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150);
    $("#aNossaArte_underline").animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#aNossaArte').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $("#aNossaArte p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
    $("#aNossaArte_underline").stop(true).animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'0px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#aNossaArte').on('click', function(){
    $("#aNossaArte p").animate({'color':'#000000'}, 150);
    $("#aNossaArte p").css({'font-weight':'bold'}, 150);
    $('#aNossaArte_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-22px'}, 150);
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
  });

  function aNossaArte_deactivate(){
    $('#aNossaArte_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
    $("#aNossaArte p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150,
      function(){
        $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
        $("#aNossaArte p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
        $("#aNossaArte p").css({'font-weight':'normal'}, 150,
          function(){
            $('#aNossaArte').on();
            $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

// Menu button "Contactos" mouse events ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤

  $('#contactos').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    $("#contactos p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150);
    $("#contactos_underline").animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#contactos').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $("#contactos p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
    $("#contactos_underline").stop(true).animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'0px'}, 150);
  });

  $('#contactos').on('click', function(){
    $("#contactos p").animate({'color':'#000000'}, 150);
    $("#contactos p").css({'font-weight':'bold'}, 150);
    $('#contactos_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-22px'}, 150);
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
  });

  function contactos_deactivate(){
    $('#contactos_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
    $('#contactos p').animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150,
      function(){
        $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
        $("#contactos p").animate({'color':'#C5C6C6'}, 150);
        $("#contactos p").css({'font-weight':'normal'}, 150,
          function(){
            $('#contactos').on();
            $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

// Running menu for the first time - aEmpresa ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
function aEmpresa_runFirstTime(){
  $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-10px'}, 150);
  $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#EF7F1A'}, 150,
    function(){
      $('#aEmpresa_underline').animate({'background-position-x':'0px', 'background-position-y':'-22px'}, 150);
      $("#aEmpresa p").animate({'color':'#000000'}, 150);
      $("#aEmpresa p").css({'font-weight':'bold'}, 150,
        function(){
          $('#aEmpresa').off();
          $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
        }
      );
    }
  );
}

// Running first time
aEmpresa_runFirstTime();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec4XA/)

Pedro

P.S. When run for the first time, the first option activates itself automaticcaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using jQuery's powerful selectors and chaining instead of separate functions for each menu item.

Here's some modified code that uses `addClass` and `removeClass` to designate the active menu item:

```
$('#menu').on('mouseenter', '> div:not(.active)', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('p').animate({
        'color': '#EF7F1A'
    }, 150).find('+ .menuUnderline').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0px',
        'background-position-y': '-10px'
    }, 150);
}).on('mouseleave', '> div:not(.active)', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('p').animate({
        'color': '#C5C6C6'
    }, 150).find('+ .menuUnderline').stop(true).animate({
        'background-position-x': '0px',
        'background-position-y': '0px'
    }, 150);
}).on('click', '> div:not(.active)', function () {
    // deactivate currently active
    $('#menu > div.active').removeClass('active').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0px',
        'background-position-y': '-10px'
    }, 150).find('p').animate({
        'color': '#C5C6C6'
    }, 150).siblings('.menuUnderline').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0px',
        'background-position-y': '0px'
    }, 150);

    // activate clicked item
    $(this).addClass('active').find('p').animate({
        'color': '#000000'
    }, 150).find('+ .menuUnderline').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0px',
        'background-position-y': '-22px'
    }, 150);
});

(function ($) {
    $('#menu + div').click();
})(jQuery);
```

Adding one more rule to your CSS simplified the jQuery a little, too:

```
#menu > div.active { cursor: default; font-weight: bold; }
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zBuZT/

(Note that the first menu item's click event will trigger on page load, just not in the context of the jsfiddle iframe.)

Comment: Hi again. There's only one issue now... I need to do a .load() to a "main content" div inside my main html file of each of the menu option's respectiv html file - aEmpresa.html, aNossaArte.html and contactos.html to #mainContent. How do I do that now?

Comment: Well, if you just want to modify what you've done already, you can add `data-href="aEmpresa.html"` (etc) to each of your menu divs. Then, at the end of the `click` handler, add
`$("#mainContent").load($(this).data("href"));`
`return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jquery data()`.

`pseudocode:`

```
if first time
{
    initialize first menu option to selected
    change `data-clicked` attribute to `true`
}

if menu_item is clicked
{
    for each item from menu
    {
        check `data-clicked` attribute
        if(true) then set to false
        else set to true
    }
}
```

You can use simple css classes too, but `data` attribute is more elegant, but this is just matter of preference.

If you wish you can also select by value of `data` atrribute like this:

```
$("[data-clicked='true']");
```

but I prefer:

```
$(item).data("hidden") === true;
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Sorry for pseudocode, I have 4kBps connection so I can't fiddle with your fiddle...

Comment: Hmmm, the pseudocode sounds logical and I checked the http://api.jquery.com/* links but I can't figure out how to apply it in my case...